# Monero RPC command for getting global index of one-time public key

Tags: daemon, rpc, stealth-address

I know there is a Monero RPC command `/get_outs` for getting one-time output (stealth address) information, including the public key, from the global index of the output. Is there a reverse command? In other words, in there a command that lets me find the global index of a one-time output from its public key? Thank you, and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, in there a command that lets me find the global index of a one-time output from its public key?

If you know (which it sounds like you do) the txid that created the output, you can just use [/get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions), which reports the global output indices in the response field `output_indices`.

If you *didn't* know the txid, there isn't an RPC method that takes as input an output public key and returns its global index. That said, it wouldn't take rocket science to write something to search the LMDB database directly.